# Set chart options when printing and add a footer

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I'm relatively new to highcharts, but I'd like to be able to take a chart and when we set it to print, which i've made the only available option, have the graphic be resized larger, increase the spacingBottom or maybe change the plot size, essentially i need to make space on the bottom and then add a label in this space.

I've figured out how to do the resize, and add the label with the events beforePrint() and afterPrint(), but the changing of the spacing on the bottom still eludes me. I've searched through the questions here, but all seem to be targeted at exporting, which I also tried, believing they were related, and they might be? I tried using the exporting.chartOptions, but that only seems to affect exporting and does nothing when we choose to print.

Thanks for any direction or help you can give.

```
$(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
                        beforePrint: function() {
                            this.resetParms = [this.chartWidth, this.chartHeight, false];
                            this.setSize(600,400,false);
                          /*eventually if I ever get this to work this is how I'd add the text.*/
                          //this.myText = this.renderer.text('this is a test',10,350 ).add();
                        },
                        afterPrint: function() {
                            this.setSize.apply(this,this.resetParms);
                        /*if(this.myText) {
                                this.myText.destroy();
                            }*/
                            Highcharts.charts.forEach(function (chart) {
                if (chart !== undefined) {
                chart.reflow();
              }
            });
                        }
                    }        
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Hours'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Hours'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    exporting:{ 
                    buttons: {
                        contextButton:{
                            menuItems: null,
                            onclick: function () {
                                this.print();
                                }
                        }
                    }
        },
  series: [{
        name: 'PY Admin',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,12],
        color: '#85C1E9',
     stack:'lyear'
    }]
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cajmrn/jkv6jbh0/3/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update bottomSpacing property with the Chart.update() function on the beforePrint event? If yes, and it did not work, use update without redraw (second argument to false) and redraw chart without animation:

```
this.update({
  chart: {
    spacingBottom: 200
  }
}, false);
this.redraw(false);
```

You could also, instead of setting spacing, set a new chart height minus the spacing you want to apply.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.redraw
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.spacingBottom

Examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/20r1z3kg/ - updating spacing
http://jsfiddle.net/xp0m4nbh/ - changing chart height with setSize()

Comment: Thanks for reply! I did try chart.update, but I definitely didn't use it with the redraw(false). I'll give your options a try today. Thanks again!